# Build iOS .ipa from Ionic 4 project inside Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, bitbucket, ipa

I have an Ionic v4 project in bitbucket, I created a pipeline to build Android APK from the project using Docker and the basic .apk building steps.

Now I have to do the same thing for iOS. I don't think Docker will be a good option since it can't really run a Mac image.

My question here is: Are there services, libraries or something else that I can use to build the .ipa on the pipeline? Preferably free with the least cost, has anyone made such things and has examples here to help me get it off the ground?

I've been looking at Microsoft App Center and CircleCI, for example, but both seem to have a cost and A LOT of capabilities that really aren't necessary in this project...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm in the same boat. macOS Big Sur is coming out with Virtualization so that might be your best bet as a free solution.

Comment: @AlexSteinberg I've been through this same problem many times in different ways and also seen many people complain about this. I also tried using Phonegap and was able to make the build, but with a lot of tweaking on the project, not really an efficient solution for a pipeline.